# Flattening an object's structure

Tags: javascript, function, object

Community! Please give me a hint.
I have the following task:

Firstly, create an object with this structure:

```
obj = {
       x: 10, 
       y: 20, 
       inner: {
          x: 20, 
          z: 30
            }, 
       foo2: {
          k: 23, 
          p: 13
       }
 }
```

Write the function convert (obj), it gets argument obj. The function should return a new object:

```
 newObj = {
    x: 20,
    y: 20,
    z: 30,
    k: 23,
    p: 13
}
```

Function should contain for ... in ... and typeof only.

I am trying to create this function, obj is copied to newObj now:

```
function convert(obj){
   newObj = {};
   for(key in obj){
      newObj[key] = obj[key];

   }
}

convert(obj);
```

But I am not sure how to use the typeof to remove the inner and foo2 sub-objects from obj and assign proper values of x, z, k and p to the newObj.

In class we were talking about basic Object calculations, so no fancy object methods are supposed to be required to solve that.

Comment: When you're iterating through every property of `obj`, you want to do different things depending on whether the property is an object or a number. These 2 behaviours can be implemented with an `if/else` and a `typeof` check. _For each property... If the property is a number, store it! Otherwise, if the property is an object, process all of the properties in that object._

Comment: Also, you probably meant to write `newObj[key] = obj[key]`

Comment: @byxor Yes, thanks, I've just corrected that.

Comment: @byxor So I should write something like:
function convert(obj){
 newObj = {};

 for(var key in obj){
  if(typeof obj[key] == 'number') {
   newObj[key] = obj[key];
  } else {
   
  }
 }
 return newObj;
}

But what should be in the else statement to process sub-objects?

Comment: Yes, you're close to a working solution. In your else statement, you either need to use recursion or another for-loop, depending on what your teacher expects of you. qiAlex's answer demonstrates the recursive approach. Merci's answer demonstrates a non-recursive approach.

Comment: I took the liberty of changing the title of your question to something that actually relates to what your asking.

Comment: @spender Hello, great, thank you :)

Comment: @byxor Thanks for taking your time on this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function convert(obj){
   newObj = {};
   for(key in obj){
     if(typeof(obj[key])==='object')
      {
       for(k in obj[key])
       {
         newObj[k]=obj[key][k]
       }
      }else{
       newObj[key]=obj[key]
      }


   }
return newObj
}
```

Comment: Unlike the recursive answers provided, this will only work to a fixed depth.

Answer (score 5):

You need a recursion in this case

```js
obj = {
   x: 10, 
   y: 20, 
   inner: {
      x: 20, 
      z: 30
        }, 
   foo2: {
      k: 23, 
      p: 13
   }
} 

function convert(obj, newObj) {
  if (!newObj) { // on first iteration creating a result object
    newObj = {}
  }
  for(key in obj){
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'number') { // if number - add, if exist - update
      newObj[key] = obj[key];
    } else { // if object - do the same one more time but for subobject and resulting object
      convert(obj[key], newObj)
    }
  }
  return newObj
}

console.log(convert(obj));
```

Comment: If the depth of the inner objects never exceeds 1, then recursion won't be needed. It's hard to know whether their professor expects them to use recursion or not. Recursion is definitely appropriate and recommended here though.

Comment: @byxor yeah, agree, it's often not clear how their tutor expects to do the task

Comment: @qiAlex Thank you! I did not know about the recursion. You've helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very neatly with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) and a little recursion.

Because the last entry for a property wins when using `Object.fromEntries`, as long as we flatten in document order, the "most recent" entry will win.

```js
const obj = {x: 10, y: 20, inner: {x: 20, z: 30}, foo2: {k: 23, p: 13}}

function* getFlattenedEntries(obj) {
  let entries = Object.entries(obj);
  for (const [k, v] of entries) {
    // typeof array is "object", so we should guard against this
    if (typeof v === "object" && !Array.isArray(v)) {
      yield* getFlattenedEntries(v);
    } else {
      yield [k, v];
    }
  }
}

const flatten = obj => Object.fromEntries(getFlattenedEntries(obj));

console.log(flatten(obj))
```